# String contains method in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

i was wondering how to use/implement string contains method in jsf2 without using JSTL.
please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<h:outputText value="#{'I love JSF'.contains('JSF')}" /> <!-- true -->
```

OR

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.text.contains('some_word')}" />
```

Comment: There is no such method. However you can similarly use other java `String` methods. So you can implement case insensitive `contains` feature like this. `#{'i love JSF'.toLowerCase().contains('JSF'.toLowerCase())}`

Answer (score 10):

In addition you can use JSTL functions

Add this:

```
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
```

And  use it like this

```
render="#{fn:contains(myBean.myText, 'test')}"
```