# ADF EL: check if an item is contained in a list

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, expression, el, oracle-adf

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0

In the backing bean, I have a List attribute called *myList*, with related public  and standard getter and setter methods, and I need to check if a String is contained inside it, in the context of an EL expression.

I have tried this expression:

```
disabled="#{myBean.myList.contains(label)}"
```

But it fails, and the message is that character ( has found instead of [ , . , or, eq, ...

I have tried to generate my custom TLD following this clear and well-explained steps [How to create a custom EL function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174), but I got an error becaus the function I declare is not found.

How can I check this condition (String contained in a List) in an EL expression?
Thanks in advance. Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An EL Expression can't pass parameters when invoking a function, but I found this link which explain an idea to simulate a passing-parameters by using a Map. It works perfect for me:
[Pass parameters from EL to a method: Simulation](http://adf-tools.blogspot.com.es/2010/09/adf-function-call-from-el-statement-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```
disabled="#{empty myBean.myList[label]}"
```

Comment: Amr Gawish, thank you for your suggestion. I solved my issue, but your idea sounds well. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but if the answer I provided is also a valid answer, can you mark it as the right answer!

Comment: I found a solution before testing your approach. So, I put the link I followed to solve it. But thank you a lot again

Answer (score 0):

If you really have an attribute of type `List` in your backing bean this should work.

You can also use it in the following ways:

```
disabled="#{myBean.myList.contains('the text')}"

disabled="#{not myBean.myList.contains(label)}" // contains not

disabled="#{myBean.myList.contains(label) eq true}"

disabled="#{!myBean.myList.contains(label)}" // contains not
```

If this doesn't work maybe something is wrong with your list.

See also:

- [How to check a boolean condition in EL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915716/how-to-check-a-boolean-condition-in-el)
- [String contains method in jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681831/string-contains-method-in-jsf)
- [Collection/Array contains method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576840/collection-array-contains-method)

Comment: thank you for your suggestions, but they don't work for me. An EL Expression can't pass parameters when invoking a function, but there is a tricky idea to make something like that. Thank you again